# Prove that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent if $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. Prove that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent for any choice of measurable functions $f$ and $g$.

This sounds very obvious, but I have no idea how to approach it.

EDIT: Two random variables are independent if $\Pr\{X = x \text{ and } Y = y\} = \Pr\{X = x\} \cdot \Pr\{Y = y\}$

Comment: Write up the definition of independentness..

Comment: I've added the definition of independence that I have.

Comment: This definition must only be for discrete $X$ and $Y$. For continuous $X$ and $Y$, all of these probabilities are generally $0$. In that situation, this definition makes $X$ and $Y$ independent no matter what.

Comment: I might suggest this definition: $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff the distribution of $X$ is identical to the distribution of $X$ under any condition put on $Y$ (like $Y=y$).

Comment: f and g have to be measurable functions and not just 'any' thing right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$X,Y$ are independent **iff** for all measurable $A,B$, the events $X^{-1}(A)$  and $Y^{-1}(B)$ are independent.

Suppose $C,D$ are measurable, and consider $(f \circ X)^{-1} ( C)$ and $(g \circ Y)^{-1} (D)$. Since $(f \circ X)^{-1} (C) = X^{-1} (f^{-1}(C))$ and $(g \circ Y)^{-1} (D)= Y^{-1} (g^{-1}(D))$. Since $X,Y$ are independent, we see that 
$X^{-1} (f^{-1}(C))$ and $Y^{-1} (g^{-1}(D))$ are independent and since $C,D$ were arbitrary, we see that $f \circ X$ and $g \circ Y$ are independent.

Comment: f and g have to be measurable functions and not just 'any' thing right?

Comment: Yes, $f,g$ must be measurable.

Comment: And that would be precisely because the composition of measurable functions is a measurable function, and by definition a random variable is a measurable function :)