# Maximum of martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, uniform-distribution, independence

I need to show whether or not the maximum of two martingales is also a martingale. Originally, I thought yes. But supposedly the answer is no. So as a counter-example, let $U_i$ be $iid$ $unif(0,1)$, $X_0 = 1$, and
$$X_n = 2^n\prod_{k=1}^n U_k.\tag{1}$$ 
I already know that $X_n$ is a martingale.

For my second martingale, let $\xi_i$ be $iid$ $Bern(p),0<p<1$, $Y_0 = 1$,
and
$$Y_n = p^{-n}\prod_{k=1}^n \xi_i.\tag{2}$$
I already know that $Y_n$ is a martingale. So let $W_n = \max(X_n,Y_n)$.
What I did was I tried to get the distribution of $W_n$ using the CDF and I ended up with
$$F_W(w) = \left(\frac{w}{2}\right)^n(1-p)^n$$

But then I got stuck. I'm not sure what to do with this. I'm not even actually sure if I am on there right track. How can I proceed to show that $W_n$ is not a martingale? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that $X_n,Y_n$ are martingales with respect to the same filtration. *However*, in my class, we had a rudimentary treatment of martingales. The main definition I know/we use is:

A stochastic process $\{X_n;n = 0,1,\dotsc\}$ is a **martingale** if for $n = 0,1,2,\dotsc,$

1. $E[|X_n|] <\infty$, and
2. $E[X_{n+1}|X_0,\dotsc,X_n] = X_n$.

   ---

This is the level of detail I need. This is what did to "show" that the sum of martingales is also a martingale:

Given that $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are martingales with respect to the same filtration, $E[|X_n|]<\infty$ and $E[|Y_n|]<\infty$. Then
$$E[|Z_n|] = E[|X_n+Y_n|] \leq E[|X_n|] + E[|Y_n|] <\infty,$$
and
\begin{align*}
E[Z_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n] &= E[X_{n+1}+Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n] \\
&= E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]+E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n] \\
&= X_n + Y_n = Z_n.
     \end{align*}
Therefore $(Z_n)$ is a martingale.

---

So, this is the level of detail I'm expected to know. So I'm stuck showing that the maximum of two martingales is not (necessarily) a martingale.

Comment: Take two independent simple random talks $S_1(n)$ and $S_2(n)$. If they are NOT equal to each other at time $n$, then $E(M_{n+1}|M_n)=M_n$. However if $S_1(n)=S_2(n)$, then $E(M_{n+1}|M_n)=M_n+\frac 3 4 - \frac 1 4\ne M_n$ - hence $M_n$ is not a martingale.

Comment: I think I get it now. We know $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are martingales w/rt their natural filtrations (by definition). It is additionally given that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are martingales w/rt to some filtration $\mathscr F_n$. Now we must show that $W_n$ is a martingale w/rt to its natural filtration. Is that right?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, that's correct. Now I must prove or disprove that $W_n$ is a martingale. My TA said that $W_n$ does not have to be a martingale. So I am trying to disprove it with a counterexample.

Comment: @Oscar How is our $W_n$ not a counterexample?

Comment: @BCLC I don't know how to show that it is a counterexample. That is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Oscar edited answer. Let me know if there's anything you don't understand

Comment: @BCLC Thanks for all your hard work! Like I mentioned, we didn't cover sigma algebras and filtrations to any meaningful depth. But I think I understand your answer since I've read about this stuff on my own. We are not expected to go into as much rigor as you have provided. Something like A.S.'s answer should suffice. But I'm not exactly sure where the $\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}$ came from.

Comment: @Oscar I'll check out AS again later. It looks to me that that is stikl using indicator functions. Whenever you have a random variable involving max or min, you usually use indicator functions. I don't think my solution involves so much rigor. It just may look like it.it's great you also do your own research. So really, which parts don't you get? Also you're welcome. This was a fun exercise for me. I didn't know this fact until recently. Wait I just realised a potential flaw in my

Comment: I think I should split up it up but its uniform no need to worry about equality I guess

Comment: @BCLC I read your comment about the filtrations, but I don't need to know that much detail.

Comment: @Oscar The counterexample by A.S. is more than sufficient for the answer.

BCLC's answers are just long calculations - the only relevant part in his answers is the last section (where he shows that the martingale property doesn't hold).

Comment: @Olorun I agree, I'm just not sure where $\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}$ comes from. Could you explain please?

Comment: @Olorun FYI I said '(proofs in first and second parts are just formalities)'

Comment: Oscar, @A.S. might be using a wrong definition of martingale. Conditioning is supposed to be on $\mathscr F_n^M = \sigma(M_0, M_1, ..., M_n)$, not just $M_n$

Comment: Oscar, you did not fully show that $Z_n$ is a martingale based on your definition. You showed that $E[Z_n | \mathscr F_{n-1}] = Z_{n-1}$. You have to show $E[Z_n | Z_0, ..., Z_{n-1}] = Z_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be specific about your filtrations.

Is it really that both $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are in the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$?

Are they both $(\{\mathscr F_n\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingales for the same filtration $\{\mathscr F_n\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}$?

I believe you mean to say that $X_n$ is a $(\{\sigma(U_1, ..., U_n)\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingale and that $Y_n$ is a $(\{\sigma(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n)\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingale.

Check your proof in saying that each is a $(\cdot, \mathbb P)-$martingale. You may have used the facts that for $m < n$,

$2^{n-m} \prod_{k=m+1}^{n} U_k$ is independent of $\sigma(U_1, ..., U_m)$

$p^{m-n} \prod_{k=m+1}^{n} \xi_k$ is independent of $\sigma(\xi_1, ..., \xi_m)$.

$W_n$ is not necessarily a $(\{\sigma(U_1, ..., U_n)\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingale or a $(\{\sigma(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n)\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingale.

---

I guess we can suppose that there's some $\{\mathscr F_n\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}$ that works for both $(*)$ s.t. $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are $(\{\mathscr F_n\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingales.

So let us try to see if $W_n$ is a $(\{\mathscr F_n\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingale.

---

Rewrite $W = (W_n)_{n \ge 0}$ using indicator functions:

$$W_n = X_n1_{A_n} + Y_n1_{A_n^C}$$

where $A_n = \{X_n \ge Y_n\}$ and $0 < P(A_n) < 1$

We have:

$$E[W_n | \mathscr F_m] = E[X_n1_{A_n} + Y_n1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_m]$$

$$ = E[X_n1_{A_n} + Y_n1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_m]$$

$$ = E[X_n1_{A_n}| \mathscr F_m] + E[Y_n1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_m]$$

$$ = X_m E[2^{n-m} \prod_{k=m+1}^{n} U_k 1_{A_n}| \mathscr F_m] + Y_m E[p^{m-n} \prod_{k=m+1}^{n} \xi_k 1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_m]$$

It does not necessarily follow that

$$E[2^{n-m} \prod_{k=m+1}^{n} U_k 1_{A_n}| \mathscr F_m] = 1_{A_m}$$

And

$$E[p^{m-n} \prod_{k=m+1}^{n} \xi_k 1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_m] = 1_{A_m^C}$$

Just because at time n, we have $A_n$ doesn't mean that at time m, we had $A_m$.

Hence, we have our counterexample.

---

Now if $P(A_j) = 0$ or $1 \ \forall j \in \mathbb N$, then $W_n$ is $X_n$ or $Y_n$ a.s., then yes, it is a $(\{\mathscr F_n\}_{(n \in \mathbb N)}, \mathbb P)-$martingale because such implies $1_{A_1} = 1_{A_2} = ...$ a.s., in particular, $1_{A_n} = 1_{A_m}$ a.s..

This might be relevant: [Is a probability of 0 or 1 given information up to time t unchanged by information thereafter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515756/)

---

However, $0 < P(A_j) < 1$ based on $0 < p < 1$:

$$P(A_j) = P(X_j \ge Y_j) = P(\xi_1 = 0 or \xi_2 = 0 or ... or \xi_j = 0)$$

$$= 1-P(\xi_1=\xi_2=...=\xi_j=1)$$

$$= 1-\prod_{i=1}^{j} (1-p)$$

$$= 1- (1-p)^j$$

---

Edit to address edit (omitting $\mathbb P$'s):

Given that $X_n$ is a $\mathscr F_n^X$-martingale, $Y_n$ is a $\mathscr F_n^Y$-martingale $(**)$ and there is some filtration $\mathscr F_n$ $(*)$ s.t. $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are $\mathscr F_n$-martingales, show that $W_n$ is a $\mathscr F_n^W$-martingale.

Using n-1 instead of m:

$$E[W_n | \mathscr F_{n-1}] = E[X_n1_{A_n} + Y_n1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_{n-1}]$$

$$ = E[X_n1_{A_n} + Y_n1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_{n-1}]$$

$$ = E[X_n1_{A_n}| \mathscr F_{n-1}] + E[Y_n1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_{n-1}]$$

$$ = X_{n-1} E[2^{n-(n-1)} \prod_{k=(n-1)+1}^{n} U_k 1_{A_n}| \mathscr F_{n-1}] + Y_{n-1} E[p^{(n-1)-n} \prod_{k=(n-1)+1}^{n} \xi_k 1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_{n-1}]$$

$$ = X_{n-1} E[2 U_n 1_{A_n}| \mathscr F_{n-1}] + Y_{n-1} E[p^{-1} \xi_n 1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_{n-1}]$$

We still run into the same problem. How can we say that

$$E[2 U_n 1_{A_n}| \mathscr F_{n-1}] = 1_{A_{n-1}}$$

or

$$E[p^{-1} \xi_n 1_{A_n^C} | \mathscr F_{n-1}] = 1_{A_{n-1}^C}$$

?

Just because at time n, we have $A_n$ doesn't mean that at time n-1, we had $A_{n-1}$.

---

$(*)$

I think some candidates for $\mathscr F_n$ are:

1. $\sigma(\sigma(U_1, ..., U_n) \cup \sigma(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n))$
2. $\sigma(\sigma(X_1, ..., X_n) \cup \sigma(Y_1, ..., Y_n))$
3. $\sigma(W_1, ..., W_n)$

I think $(3) \subseteq (2) \subseteq (1)$

I think $\sigma(A_1, ..., A_n) \subseteq (2), \subseteq (1), \subsetneq (3)$

---

$(**)$

FYI

$$\sigma(U_1, ..., U_n) \supseteq \mathscr F_n^X$$

$$\sigma(\xi_1, ..., \xi_n) \supseteq \mathscr F_n^Y$$

More info here: [Prove Z is a martingale by defining it is a product of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494831/prove-z-is-a-martingale-by-defining-it-is-a-product-of-random-variables)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't have to go into this much detail I think. I'm in an introductory course. We didn't cover $\sigma-$algebras or filtrations in any depth.

Comment: @Oscar What don't you understand? Just ignore $\mathbb P$ I guess. Also you can replace $m$ with $n-1$. Anyway, the main idea is rewriting $W_n$ using indicator functions. Going to edit.

Comment: @Oscar Oh right, edited

Comment: @Oscar Edited..

Answer (score 0):

Oscar, are you sure you know why your examples are 'martingales'?

---

(proofs in first and second parts are just formalities)

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ be our probability space.

Let $Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, ...$ be iid random variables s.t. $P(Y_i = 1) = 1/2 = P(Y_i = -1)$. Define $W^Y_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n} Y_i$.

Let $X_0, X_1, X_2, ...$ be iid random variables s.t. $P(X_i = 1) = 1/2 = P(X_i = -1)$. Define $W^X_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i$.

---

Firstly, note that $W^X_n$ and $W^Y_n$ martingales w/rt their natural filtrations (this corresponds to your definition of martingale) ie

$$E[W^X_n|W^X_0, W^X_1, ..., W^X_{n-1}] = E[W^X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] = W^X_{n-1}$$

$$E[W^Y_n|W^Y_0, W^Y_1, ..., W^Y_{n-1}] = E[W^Y_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^Y}] = W^Y_{n-1}$$

They are also martingales w/rt to the natural filtrations of X and Y, resp ie

$$E[W^X_n|X_0, X_1, ..., X_{n-1}] = E[W^X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{X}] = W^X_{n-1}$$

$$E[W^Y_n|Y_0, Y_1, ..., Y_{n-1}] = E[W^Y_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{Y}] = W^Y_{n-1}$$

Actually, the latter equations are easier to prove than the former equations.

---

Proof of the former equations (I'll just use X):

$$\mathscr F_{n-1}^{X} \supseteq \mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X} \tag{*}$$

Then we have

$$E[W^X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] = E[X_0 + X_1 + ... + X_{n-1} + X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}]$$

$$ = E[X_0 + X_1 + ... + X_{n-1}|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] + E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}]$$

Consider the first term.

$$E[X_0 + X_1 + ... + X_{n-1}|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} E[X_{i}|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}]$$

Consider the summand. Convince yourself that $X_i$ is $\mathscr F_{i}^{W^X}$-measurable (if we know $X_0, X_0 + X_1, ..., X_0 + X_1 + ... + X_i$, then we know $X_i$). Then $\because \mathscr F_{i}^{W^X} \subseteq \mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}$, we have that $X_i$ is $\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}$-measurable. Hence,

$$E[X_{i}|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] = X_i$$

Consider the second term $$E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}]$$

By $(*)$ and the the [tower property of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties), we have

$$E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] = E[E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}]|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{X}]$$

Essentially, the tower property of conditional expectation states that the smaller filtration wins. Hence, it is also true that

$$E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] = E[E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{X}]|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}]$$

Thus, we have

$$E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] = E[E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}]|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{X}] = E[E[X_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{X}]|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}]$$

By independence, we have:

$$= E[E[X_n]|\mathscr F_{n-1}^{W^X}] = E[X_n] = 0$$

Hopefully, you're convinced that it's much easier to prove the latter than the former equations.

---

Secondly, consider

$$M_n = W_n^X 1_{A_n} + W_n^Y 1_{A_n^C}$$

where $A_n = \{W_n^X \ge W_n^Y\}$ and $0 < P(A_n) < 1$

Let us try to show (and hopefully fail in trying) that

$$E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^M] = M_{n-1}$$

where $\mathscr F_{n-1}^M = \sigma(M_0, M_1, ..., M_{n-1})$

Hopefully, you understand that it's possible to do the following:

$$E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^M] = E[E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}]|\mathscr F_{n-1}^M]$$

where $\mathscr F_{n} := \sigma(\mathscr F_{n}^X, \mathscr F_{n}^Y) \supseteq \sigma(\mathscr F_{n}^{W^X}, \mathscr F_{n}^{W^Y}) \supseteq \mathscr F_n^M$

Thus, if $E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = M_{n-1}$, then $E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^M] = M_{n-1}$. So hopefully, $E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] \ne M_{n-1}$.

---

Finally, let's compute

$$E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = E[W_n^X 1_{A_n} + W_n^Y 1_{A_n^C}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] $$

$$= E[W_n^X 1_{A_n}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] + E[W_n^Y 1_{A_n^C}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] $$.

Now consider this. If at time 1, we have that $W_1^X = 2$ and $W_1^Y = 1$, it's possible that $W_2^X = 1$ and $W_2^Y = 2$. Thus, $M_2 = W_2^Y$ but $M_1 = W_1^X$

Formally:

If at time n, we have $\omega \in A_n$ (ie $W_n^X(\omega) \ge W_n^Y(\omega)$), then

$$E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = E[W_n^X 1_{A_n}|\mathscr F_{n-1}] + 0$$

$$= E[W_n^X|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = W_{n-1}^X$$

But is it that $W_{n-1}^X = M_{n-1}$?

Not necessarily. It could be that $\omega \in A_{n-1}^C$ (ie $W_{n-1}^X(\omega) \le W_{n-1}^Y(\omega)$). Hence, $M_{n-1} = W_{n-1}^Y$

$\therefore, \because$ it is not necessarily true that $E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}] = M_{n-1}$, it does not follow that $E[M_n|\mathscr F_{n-1}^M] = M_{n-1}$ QED