# If $(Y_n)$ is independent and $X_n=\prod\limits_{k=0}^nY_k$, what is $\bigcap\limits_n \sigma(X_k\,;\,k\geqslant n)$?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ be independent random variables. 
For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define

$$X_n:=Y_0Y_1\cdots Y_n.$$

Is it true that $\bigcap\limits_n \sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\dots)=\bigcap\limits_n \sigma(Y_{n+1},Y_{n+2},\dots)?$

Otherwise, how to show that $\bigcap\limits_n \sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\dots)$ and $\sigma(Y_1,Y_2,\dots)$ are independent?

The question [Prove random variable $Y_0$ and $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{R}$ are independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445218/), about the symmetric Bernoulli case when $P(Y_n=1)=P(Y_n=-1)=\frac12$, is related.